# Rails use a non-id column for model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

How can I specify a column for a Rails model association to use as its foreign_key? This is "id" by default, and I would like to specify another column.

---

**Example:**

question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end
```

answer.rb

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Both the "questions" and "answers" table do not use the **id** column. Instead they both use the **stack_overflow_id** column for their primary_keys (they came from the StackOverflow API).

---

Here is the code that should be able to run:

```
my_question = Question.find(stack_overflow_id: 55)
answers = my_question.answers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is two functionalities:

1. Overriding the foreign key for an association.  This is done with the `foreign_key` parameter on an association: `belongs_to :question, foreign_key: "stack_overflow_id"`.  This will allow you to do `instance.association` and get the correct records back.
2. Finding a record by parameters, rather than the automatically created ID field.  This is accomplished using `Model.where(stack_overflow_id: 55)` (for more than one record) or by using `find_by(stack_overflow_id: 55)` (for the first/only record with that ID.  Check out the APIs for these commands, because they don't match the API for `find`.